# Change specific values in GSMA TAP3 file

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, struct

I'm trying to change charge values from MO (originating) calls in GSM TAP3.11 files, but it doesn't handle the needed

here i can access directly duration value but with charge value its different case as attached, im tring to change the charge value on `(1) chargeDetail` and `(2) chargeDetail` (first and second records in the `ChargeDetailList` in the screenshot below).

[image]

My background is only with python, this's the first time with perl. I use it because after searching I believe that only perl can handle TAP files.  (see [TAP3::Tap3edit](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/TAP3-Tap3edit/lib/TAP3/Tap3edit.pod))

```
$struct=$tap3->structure;

my $key;

# Will scan all the calls for MOC's.
foreach $key ( @{$struct->{'transferBatch'}->{'callEventDetails'} } ) {

    foreach ( keys %{$key} ) {

        if ( $_ eq "mobileOriginatedCall" )
        {
            $duration= $key->{$_}->{'basicCallInformation'}->{'totalCallEventDuration'};
            delete $key->{$_}{'basicCallInformation'}{'basicServiceUsedList'}[0]{'chargeInformationList'}[0]{'chargeDetailList'}[0]{'charge'};
            $key->{$_}{'basicCallInformation'}{'basicServiceUsedList'}[0]{'chargeInformationList'}[0]{'chargeDetailList'}[0]{'charge'}=$duration * 0.12 /0.6;
            $new_charge_value = $key->{$_}{'basicCallInformation'}{'basicServiceUsedList'}[0]{'chargeInformationList'}[0]{'chargeDetailList'}[0]{'charge'}=$duration * 0.12 /0.6;


        }
    }
}

$tap3->encode("$tap_file")  or  die $tap3->error;
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and welcome to Perl 5! :)  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56705231/edit) to include more information.  For example, would you please add how you are creating `$tap3`, and what happens when you run your current code?  Thanks!

Comment: sorry in still newbee with perl, here im trying to change the charge value

Comment: mashro3ak, Perl people generally like to see folks learning the language :) .  In order to answer your question, we need more information.  The best thing is a small program we can run to reproduce your problem, and a copy of your TAP3 file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exists() function in Perl is used to check whether an element in an given array or hash exists or not. This function returns 1 if the desired element is present in the given array or hash else returns 0.

```
$Tax_Rate = 3;
$Exchange_Rate = 3;
$Rate_Plan_Charge_Rate = 8;
my $key;

# Will scan all the calls for MOC's.
foreach $key ( @{$struct->{'transferBatch'}->{'callEventDetails'} } ) {

    foreach ( keys %{$key} ) {

        if ( $_ eq "mobileOriginatedCall" )
        {
            if (exists $key->{$_}->{'basicCallInformation'}->{'totalCallEventDuration'}){

                $duration = $key->{$_}->{'basicCallInformation'}->{'totalCallEventDuration'};

                if (exists $key->{$_}->{basicServiceUsedList}[0]{chargeInformationList}[0]{chargeDetailList}[0]){

                    $key->{$_}->{basicServiceUsedList}[0]{chargeInformationList}[0]{chargeDetailList}[0]{charge}=($duration * $Rate_Plan_Charge_Rate) / $Exchange_Rate;
                }
                if (exists $key->{$_}->{basicServiceUsedList}[0]{chargeInformationList}[0]{chargeDetailList}[1]){

                    $key->{$_}->{basicServiceUsedList}[0]{chargeInformationList}[0]{chargeDetailList}[1]{charge}=($duration * $Rate_Plan_Charge_Rate) / $Exchange_Rate;
                }
                $New_Charge = $key->{$_}->{basicServiceUsedList}[0]{chargeInformationList}[0]{chargeDetailList}[0]{charge};

                if (exists $key->{$_}->{basicServiceUsedList}[0]{chargeInformationList}[0]{taxInformation}[0]){

                    $key->{$_}->{basicServiceUsedList}[0]{chargeInformationList}[0]{taxInformation}[0]{taxValue}=($New_Charge / $Tax_Rate);
                }
                if (exists $key->{$_}->{basicServiceUsedList}[0]{chargeInformationList}[0]{taxInformation}[1]){

                    $key->{$_}->{basicServiceUsedList}[0]{chargeInformationList}[0]{taxInformation}[0]{taxValue}=($New_Charge / $Tax_Rate);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```